# Error running spark simple app without installing spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-java

I am learning spark. And trying to run a simple spark app that output 5 dataframe rows without installing spark. I know that one can run spark app without installing spark. The app is throwing below error and I could not resolve the issue. I have tried solution posted on snowflake to similar problem but in vain. Below is the error log for your reference.
Using below softwares:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902

> java -version
> openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:916)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:916)
    at net.jgp.books.spark.ch01.lab100_csv_to_dataframe.CsvToDataframeApp.start(CsvToDataframeApp.java:32)
    at net.jgp.books.spark.ch01.lab100_csv_to_dataframe.CsvToDataframeApp.main(CsvToDataframeApp.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @35dab4eb
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
    ... 16 more
```

I tried the solutions here [Why am I seeing `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible` on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019371/why-am-i-seeing-java-lang-reflect-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-p)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling java again. I am a newbie.

Comment: What is the command you use to execute your code?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE. I right-click in the code section and select "Run As -> java application"

Comment: and are you 100% sure that java 11 is being used there? [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading) mentions that only java 8/11 and version 17 is supported from spark 3.3.0 only

Comment: I am not sure what is used while application is running. But I am sure I have open jdk 11.

Comment: I see this in eclipse configuration.
```
-vm
C:/Users/xxxx/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.4.v20221004-1257/jre/bin\server\jvm.dll
```
Do you think I should install jre 17?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to your Spark session builder

```
  SparkSession.builder()
  // your setting
  .config(
    "spark.sql.extensions",
    "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions"
  )
```